# If loop, error in macro

Tags: java, arrays, split, macros

Hi I am trying to make a macro for imagej.
Now I have as input a vector Array1y about 300 elements. If I would like to subdivide the vector in subvectors, how can i do? If for example I want 100 subvectors, so a step of 30, I was thinking to something like that

```
w=30;
step= Array1y.length/w
for (i=0; i<Array1y.length; i+=(w+1)) 
{
for (j=w; j<Array1y.length ; j+=w)
a(i)= Array.slice(Array1y,i,w)
Array.print a(i)
}
}
```

what's wrong? 
Can it work if I have no 300 elements but less, let's say 268 and I want as well a step of 30 (so I have the last subvector that is not made by 30 elements?)

Comment: "what's wrong?" indentation? More serioulsy, you probably should read about [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)

Comment: is this java or javascript? because .slice is from js right?

Comment: it's a ijm file for a macro to implement in imagej

Comment: Actually, the problem was not about the division but on the "for" line!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, or if it is actually `java`, but here's what I think you asked for :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vector = new int[268];
    IntStream.range(0, vector.length).forEach(i -> vector[i] = i); // to fill the vector
    int subvectorSize = 30;
    int[][] subvectors = new int[vector.length/subvectorSize+1][subvectorSize];  // array of arrays
    for(int i=0; i< vector.length; i++){  // iterate over vector
        int x = i/subvectorSize; // get quotient (xth subvector)
        int y = i%subvectorSize; // get reminder (index y of subvector)
        subvectors[x][y] = vector[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subvectors));
}
```

That outputs :

> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89], [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119], [120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149], [150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179], [180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209], [210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239], [240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 0, 0]]